# Jquery flip effect

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/r3thre5q/6/

I have an image with text hidden below.

I'd like to show the text when you hover over the image.

I can do it fading the image out and sliding the image out.

I'd also like to do it were the image flips to show the text.

I'm  using this tutorial here http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip that uses css but I can't seem to get it to work with jQuery.

How can I use this flip effect with jQuery.

```
    $(function () {

        $(".fade").hover(function () {
            $('.info-front').fadeTo('fast', 0.2);
        }, function () {
            $('.info-front').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        });

        $(".slide").hover(function () {
            $('.info-front').animate({bottom:'-300px'});
        }, function () {
            $('.info-front').animate({bottom:'0'});
        });

        $(".flip").hover(function () {
            $('.info-block').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
        }, function () {
            $('.info-block').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
        });

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited some of your code. You will need to play a little bit more for the text. Check it our here: http://jsfiddle.net/r3thre5q/8/

I've changed the $.hover adding 0deg

```
$(".flip").hover(function () {
  $('.info-block').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
}, function () {
  $('.info-block').css('transform', 'rotateY(0deg)');
});
```

I've changed the css too:

```
.flip {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```